# Need to sort Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, input

I need to code a voting system, with candidate names and input.

Each voter will be given a screen with JTextfields to score each candidate, each score goiing into an array where i is the candidate number and score[i] is the candidate score.

I am having trouble sorting the arrays from highest score to lowest whilst being able to see which candidate has which score and then being able to use that to display the winner.

I have seen bubble sorting but that does not always sort it exactly from high to  low and i've also seen the Arrays.sort(ArrayName); method.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't put scores in an array. Put Candidate objects in an array, store the score of each candidate in the corresponding Candidate object, and sort the array of Candidates by score. In short, Java is an OO language. Use objects.

Comment: If you associate the index with some property (candidate), then clearly you cannot sort as all the indices would change. Possible solutions include using objects, or if you haven't learned them yet, parallel arrays. However, if all you want is the winner, why not just find the largest element?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using parallel arrays, and if so, stop. Instead move away from the GUI program for a minute and instead create some decent OOP compliant classes, including a class for Candidate which holds the score and candidateNumber data. Then it would be easy to sort your collection (such as an `ArrayList<Candidate>`) using `Collections.sort(...)`. If your Candidate class implements the `Comparable<Candidate>` interface, then your job gets even easier still since no Comparitor class would be needed. Note that if you have the class implement Comparable, you'll need to give it a `public int compareTo(Candidate o)` method that will return an int, 1, 0, or -1, depending on the score of the `o` Candidate vs. `this` Candidate's score.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i will take this into account when i start the programming. Just another question, how do you create an arraylist with 2 properties, and sort it by one?

Comment: Sorry I am still quite new to java

Comment: I would not advise making a Candidate Comparable and implement the compareTo method based on score. The general rule is that Comparable should be consistent with equals(), and two candidates should not be equal if they have the same score. A Comparator, IMHO, is the best option here: it sorts candidates based on a specific use-case. Another use-case might want to sort them by name or by ID.

Comment: @HaseebTahir you don't create an ArrayList with two properties. You crate a class name Candidate, with two properties (name and score, for example). Then you create an ArrayList<Candidate>, and store instances of Candidate in the list.